# Roads and places database?

Tags: gps, mapping, directions

I'm trying to determine if there's a database or API available that I could use to get detailed roadway data, meaning the shape and length of roads, intersection points, speed limits, exit numbers for highways, etc.

Obviously Google, MapQuest and others have access to this information and use it to give you driving directions, but I'd like to do something else with the data.

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score -1):

You can use OpenStreetMap database, which contains the mentioned data and much more. You can read more on [OpenStreetMap Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm)

Please mind the [OpenStreetMap license](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)